# I have a .bowerrc and a bower.json file does a project need both?

Tags: bower, asp.net-core-mvc

In an ASP.NET Core MVC website there is a [.bowerrc](http://bower.io/docs/config/) file:

```
{
  "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

And there is also a `bower.config` file:

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "4.5.0",
    "startbootstrap-sb-admin-2": "1.0.8"
  }
}
```

Should the project have both, does it need both? If so, what is the purpose of each?
Both files are in the root directory of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of bower.json is to define all the dependencies your project have. The purpose of .bowerrc is to define optional configurations such as the location of the directory bower must work and other things (proxy, etc.).

To answer your question, normally .bowerrc can be optional but in your case, it looks like a specific directory is set for bower to install packages into.